# Mocking service method with generics

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have to mock this service

```
@Service
public class RelationServiceImpl implements RelationService {

    @Autowired
    private Map<String, Class<? extends Historiable>> modelRelations;


    @Override
    public Class<? extends Historiable> getModel(String collectionName) {

        return modelRelations.get(collectionName);
    }

}
```

But I don't know how to define behaviour on the test. When I try this

```
    @Mock
    private RelationService relationService;

        @Test
        public void getHistoryOk2() throws NotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException {
            ...



 when(relationService.getModel(eq(collectionName))).thenReturn(ShipmentRequest.class);
            ...

     }
```

I get an compiler error saying this:

```
The method thenReturn(Class<capture#1-of ? extends Historiable>) in the type OngoingStubbing<Class<capture#1-of ? extends Historiable>> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<ShipmentRequest>)
```

But ShipmentRequest is a child Class of Historiable

```
Historiable
|
|-ShipmentRequest
|-...
|-...
```

I've tried this too. Instead of using ShipmentRequest.class in the "thenReturn" part, call this method instead

```
when(relationService.getModel(eq(collectionName))).thenReturn(method());

    private Class<? extends Historiable> method(){
            return ShipmentRequest.class;
        }
```

But the error changes to this

```
The method thenReturn(Class<capture#1-of ? extends Historiable>) in the type OngoingStubbing<Class<capture#1-of ? extends Historiable>> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#3-of ? extends Historiable>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An additional cast is needed:

```
     when((Class<ShipmentRequest>)relationService.getModel(eq(collectionName))).thenReturn(ShipmentRequest.class);
```